# Force close all open popups from code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to cause all open popups (with StaysOpen == false) to close from code.  Basically I want to simulate the user clicking the mouse (which would close the popups) from code.

I don't need to actually simulate the click, I just need the resulting behavior.  I've thought about just going through the visual tree looking for popups and closing each one, but that doesn't seem like the cleanest approach.

Thanks in advance for any help or opinions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A WPF popup actually creates a new window (a Win32 window, not a WPF `Window` instance). So you can't find it in the `Application.Windows` collection, but you can probably find it using a Win32 API like [`EnumChildWindows`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumchildwindows).

Once you have the handle, you can retrieve the associated `HwndSource`. I think the `RootVisual` of the `HwndSource` is the `Popup` (didn't check, you might have to look deeper in the visual tree).

So the code should be similar to this (completely untested):

```
public static class PopupCloser
{
    public static void CloseAllPopups()
    {
        foreach(Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            CloseAllPopups(window);
        }
    }

    public static void CloseAllPopups(Window window)
    {
        IntPtr handle = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
        EnumChildWindows(handle, ClosePopup, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    private static bool ClosePopup(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        HwndSource source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(hwnd);
        if (source != null)
        {
            Popup popup = source.RootVisual as Popup;
            if (popup != null)
            {
                popup.IsOpen = false;
            }
        }
        return true; // to continue enumeration
    }

    private delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hwndParent, EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);

}
```

Comment: ClosePopup signature has void() but you are returning bool.

Comment: I've encountered few special cases where popup.IsOpen=false wont do anything. If someone is facing similiar issue, I suggest you to generate mouse click using winapi @ (0,0). This will close StaysOpen=false popups.

Comment: I couldn't get EnumChildWindows to work and ended up using EnumThreadWindows instead.

Answer (score 1):

Going through the visual tree is the way to do it that isn't dependent in any way on how you've created them in the first place.  There may be much cleaner ways of doing it, but they all really depend on your implementation.

For instance, all of the Popups in my application are bound to view model objects that expose some kind of `IsOpen` property that the Popup binds to.  If I needed to implement this functionality in my project, I'd just maintain a collection of these objects (or a generator method) that I could iterate over, and set `IsOpen` to false on each.  This obviously won't work if you aren't building your UI the way I am, though.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3886139/12885902) wasn't doing the trick for me, because `source.RootVisual` was never of type `Popup` but of the internal type `PopupRoot`. The following tweak got the code to work:

```
private void CloseAllPopups()
{
    foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
    {
        IntPtr handle = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
        EnumThreadWindows(handle, ClosePopup, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}

private static bool ClosePopup(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam)
{
    HwndSource source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(hwnd);
    if (source?.RootVisual?.GetType().Name == "PopupRoot")
    {
        if (LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(source.RootVisual) is Popup popup)
        {
            popup.IsOpen = false;
        }
    }
    return true; // to continue enumeration
}

private delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(IntPtr hwndParent, EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);
```

Please also keep in mind that the CloseAllPopups() method has to be called by the main UI thread (e.g. `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke()`)!

Comment: I found out that in my case even this solution is only working if the debugger of Visual Studio was attached. See my other answer for the real solution

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer was also not working all the time. It only worked when the Visual Studio debugger was attached to the process. What ended up working in any case is the following:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    PresentationSource.CurrentSources.OfType<HwndSource>()
        .Select(h => h.RootVisual)
        .OfType<FrameworkElement>()
        .Select(f => f.Parent)
        .OfType<Popup>()
        .Where(popup => popup.IsOpen)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(popup => popup.SetCurrentValue(Popup.IsOpenProperty, false));
});
```

Comment: Nice solution. However, to preserve any `IsOpen` bindings you should instead use `popup => popup.SetCurrentValue(Popup.IsOpenProperty, false)`. Also, there is no need for `.Where(popup => popup.IsOpen)`.

Comment: Thanks for your improvement idea! Using `SetCurrentValue` is indeed very advisable, I changed the code above. I would not recommend to remove the `.Where(popup => popup.IsOpen)` however, as there can be very many Popups that are currently not open and don't need to be closed. You are however right, that this line is not needed.

Comment: Having `.Where(popup => popup.IsOpen)` will merely reduce the size of the list. A `DependencyProperty` will not signal a value change when setting the same value. So, in a way, you could argue that the condition is sort of an optimization.

Comment: @l33t yes you are right, this is only an optimization

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare somewhere static array of opened popups:

   `static List<Popup> openedPopups = new List<Popup>();`
2. Before open popup close all previsiously opened popups:

   `private void TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
        // close all before opene popup
        openedPopups.ForEach(p => p.IsOpen = false); 
        openedPopups.Clear(); // clear opened popus's collection, because they were closed
        Popup1.IsOpen = true; // open popup I need open now
        openedPopups.Add(Popup1); // remember it for future close
   }`