# Popup.Stays Open false not working

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

This is follow up of below question,
[How to close popup window when dialog box open in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536679/how-to-close-popup-window-when-dialog-box-open-in-wpf)

I'm having `Popup` and it's `StaysOpen` was set to false. Now, if an Explorer window is open by pressing Windows+<kbd>E</kbd>, then the Popup closed. But if it was not closed when a File Dialog is open with some key combination.

Comment: It was working fine with a simple example. So could you elaborate the question in detail?

Comment: Please try this solution in your scenario, normally the popup getting closed when opening dialog, or you can try out this scenario http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885975/force-close-all-open-popups-from-code

Comment: `StaysOpen=False` isn't working in all cases for me too... specially when you open the popup, focus it, and then hit a key shortcut for focus somewhere else programatically: this action will not close the popup